Android tradingview lightweightchart pricescale bug
I have a tradingview lightweight chart in android and I use their own library. It should show price chart of some currency (say BTC).
Here is what I've tried:
I've created a chart both without priceScaleId and with priceScaleId equal to left, and what happens is shown in the below image:

As you can see, the range shown for the image, is far bigger than the data range (And I've checked it with my code and data is not corrupted).
But when I set the priceScaleId to right, it works fine as the image below shows:

I've created an Issue on their repository, but they haven't responded so far.
Does any body have any idea how to fix the problem in left priceScale?
